# fetch data on name selection or entered

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

We are building an advanced form with following fields...

```
<input type="text" size="50" name="name" >
<input type="text" size="50" name="custid" >
<input type="text" size="50" name="projectname" >
<input type="text" size="50" name="overdue" >
```

We are using jquery autocomplete to select name from MySQL and what we would like to do is:

We want to add **custid, projectname**, and **overdue** to their fields after adding **name** automatically, we can do it in PHP but how can we do it using jQuery or ajax? Can you help us to write up the code? We can add 1 output using ajax but how do we add multiple outputs?  thanks.

Comment: i think we should use json in this case, if yes then how to output json data using php and how to use those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could retrieve the remaining fields using AJAX, by having a PHP script which outputs their details in JSON format. So if your data is stored in an associative array called `$data`, you can simply do `echo json_encode( $data );`. Each field name in the array, will be the name of the instance variable you'll need to call in the jQuery. The code below assumes your array field names are the same as your inputs.

You then use `jQuery.get( )` (or similarly `jQuery.ajax( )`) to obtain the result. jQuery below:

```
$.get('myscript.php', 
      {name: name},
      function(data) {
        // If successful, fill out the fields
        $('#custid').val(data.custid);
        $('#projectname').val(data.projectname);
        $('#overdue').val(data.overdue);
      },
      // tells jQuery it's retrieving a JSON encoded object
      'json'
);
```

This will also require you to slightly alter your HTML as below:

```
<input type="text" size="50" name="custid" id="custid" >
<input type="text" size="50" name="projectname" id="projectname" >
<input type="text" size="50" name="overdue" id="overdue" >
```

Comment: but how to use retrieved json results, what if we use success() and how to get value for our input fields?

Comment: Just noticed - I forgot to put the data to send to your PHP in the jQuery! It's there now.